# How to use - Transit bus real time data access

Tags: api

I go to this website (http://www.calgarytransit.com/survey/real-time-data-access) to apply for real time data access. After successfully applied, I got reply with access urls like below:

> Thanks for registering for access to our Real-Time data. You can
>   access the Real Time data at the following links:

http://transitdata.calgary.ca/ctransit/tripupdates.pb

http://transitdata.calgary.ca/ctransit/alerts.pb

http://transitdata.calgary.ca/ctransit/vehiclepositions.pb

I see the urls with extension .pb but not sure how to use them. So I just paste the urls in a browser and I got this error message:

> Server Error
>
> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I was also in the same situation. After some R&D I got to know about Protocol Buffer. Then I created one method in C# to access these APIs. I am sharing my solution with you. You will definitely get some hints.
    
    `string url = "<Your url>.pb";
    HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(url));
    webReq.Method = "GET";
    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("user_name", "password");
    CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache { { new Uri(url), "Basic", networkCredential } };
    webReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
    webReq.Credentials = myCredentialCache;
    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
    Stream answer = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader _recivedAnswer = new StreamReader(answer);
    FeedMessage message = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<FeedMessage>(_recivedAnswer.BaseStream);` 

The code is in C#. Here, I want to get the response and deserialize the response using `ProtoBuff.Serializer`. I needed two Nuget packages for this. one is protobuf-net for ProtoBuf and GtfsRealtimeBindings for the FeedMessage.
For more detail, visit the following links.

1. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/serialization-and-deserialization-ib-c-sharp-using-protobuf-dll/
2. https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/examples/dotnet-sample
3. https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/gtfs-realtime-proto
4. http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/working-with-google-protocol-buffers-and-.net.html